# how to read images from xml file?

Tags: xml, xcode, ios4

how to read images from xml file in xcode project?
How did we display that image in iphone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `NSCoding`, you convert the `UIImage` to some `NSData`. Then you add the `NSData` object to an array or an `NSDictionary` and finally you save that `NSDictionary` to the disk. Or whatever you want to do with the XML file.

Comment: @user593344   http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSKeyedArchiver_Class/Reference/Reference.html